# Google Sheets - App Script (copyTo - cell content & format)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy

I have a tracker to count daily productivity.

This is appended to a weekly tracker, in which the sum of the two serves as a running total.

The weekly tracker is appended to a separate sheet to serve as historical data.

[TRACKER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK9v0.png)

[DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVJe3.png)

As you can see in the 'DATA' screenshot, the formula is being copied from K12:O12

- see function copyTT / source.copyTo

I want to retain cell formatting, and copy only the cell data, not it's formula.

Script;

```
function mergeTT() { 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet (); 

var source = ss.getRange("NEW_TTRACKER!J3:O3"); 

var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("NEW_TTRACKER"); 

var lastRow = destSheet.getRange("J7:J11").getValues().filter(String).length;

var destRange = destSheet.getRange(lastRow+7,10,1,6); 

source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});

var ws = ss.getSheetByName("NEW_TTRACKER")

ws.getRange('K3:O3').clearContent();

} 

function copyTT() { 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet (); 

var source = ss.getRange("NEW_TTRACKER!J5:O12"); 

var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("NEW_TDATA");

var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1); 

source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: false});

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("NEW_TTRACKER"); 

sheet.getRange('J7:O11').clearContent(); 

}
```

Thanks in advance.

I've been attempting to get around it playing with different CopyPasteType properties and I'm really not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About `I've been attempting to get around it playing with different CopyPasteType properties`, I think that your approach is correct. In your script, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
```

#### To:

```
source.copyTo(destRange, { contentsOnly: true });
source.copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false); // Added
```

- By this modification, the format is also copied.

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)

Comment: Thank you sir, this works perfectly.

Also explains where I was going wrong.

To me that looks like it does the opposite of what I want it to do.
Thus I was doing the opposite of this.

Looks like I have some reading to do.

Thank you.